# Angular directive loading order

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Packery in a directive as in the example here

[Packery angular directive](http://codepen.io/gruntruk/pen/Cpewt/)

```
enter code here
```

I am also creating dynamic elements as described here [angular dynamic templates](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/)

in which I wish to apply the directive to however I believe the packery directive is loaded before the dynamic template gallery so the new content is not working with packery , I am looking for a way to ensure the dynamic content works with the packery directive

Comment: You should use the [priority](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-priority-) attribute of a directive.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this it did not seem to have an impact on the order of loading... i set the priority on the directive which loads the template to 1 and the other to 0